# How do we get the contribution grid populated with contribution data in the Gitlab profile page for a particular user?

Tags: gitlab, analytics, gitlab-api

In the Gitlab Profile for a user, if we want to see the Activity for the certain user, its visible as contributions per day of the year in blue grids. How do we get the contribution grid populated with contribution data in the Gitlab profile page for a particular user?
Would appreciate if someone can point me towards the source code which generates that!

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/gitlab/contributions_calendar.rb

Comment: Thanks a lot Sascha Frinken